# how to assign constant address to pointer at pascal?

Tags: delphi, debugging, pointers, pascal, jedi-code-library

I can't find how i can set constant address to pointer in Delphi (Pascal). I need it for search unit and linenumber in map file with jclDebug.
For example:

```
var
  P : pointer;
  info : TjclLocationInfo;
begin
  P := $016199E3;
  info := jclDebug.getLocationInfo(P);
end;
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Simply cast to a pointer: `P := Pointer($016199E3);`